# How to adjust image size of an org-babel output permanently?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I know I can add html or latex attributes under the `#+result:` block after executing the block, but when I re-evaluate the block, it is removed.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795548/how-do-you-get-org-mode-to-export-a-wide-or-long-table-so-its-readable-in-pdf/57812984?noredirect=1#comment102058316_57812984) for a way to attach attributes to the result.

Comment: @NickD Works like a charm. May I ask one more question? It is possible to get attributes work with `:results: ... :end:` block? When a babel block generate multiple image outputs, they are wrapped into such block, and the method mentioned in the link does not work.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head: I suggest you make it into a separate question.